# Why isn't this relation transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

Here's a question from my e-text:

[image]

By definition, a relation $R$ on $A$ is transitive if whenever $xRy$ and $yRz$, then $xRz$. That is, the logic is sort of like a "chain" or a hypothetical syllogism, if you will.

So in the diagram above, you have $xQy$ and $yQx$, and you also have $xQx$, so why isn't this transitive? I don't quite understand their logic.

Comment: Oh, okay, I think I got it. So a relation isn't transitive if "there is a case where this is satisfied". It's only transitive if it is satisfied for all such cases in the relation, i.e. we would have had to have $y$ mapping to itself in the diagram. Here, however, $y$ maps to $x$, $x$ maps to $y$, but $y$ doesn't map to $y$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is only one case. You have to check that *for all elements $a,b,c$ in the set* on which the relation is being made, if it is true that $aRb$ and $bRc$, then it should also be true that $ aRc$. You have checked this for *only one possible assignment of $a,b,c$*, namely $a=c=x$ and $b=y$. You should also check what happens when $a=c=y$ and $b=x$, which is another possibility. This translates to : If $yRx$ and $xRy$ then $yRy$, which is not true here. Hence, the relation is not transitive.

> Moral of the story : transitivity must be checked for **all** possible values of $a,b,c$. That is to say, for **all** triples of elements $(a,b,c)$ from the set, whenever it happens that $aRb$ and $aRc$, it must happen that $aRc$, but that is not the case above for **all** possibilities, although it is true in **one** case (the one you pointed out). So it's really the difference between *one* and *all*.

Comment: Thank you! My misunderstanding stemmed from the fact that when the text defined transitivity, it only presented a case where it WAS satisfied, without elaborating that you could have a relation that is not transitive because "parts" of it do not display this behavior.

Comment: @AleksandrH Textbooks! I say, this is the best place to clarify concepts, because textbooks can miss the ocasional point, but the sheer wealth on this site is enough to take care of all our concepts. Now I hope you understand the concept. By the way, you are not alone: many people still fail  to understand transitivity, so I am happy that we have cleared it up here. +1 for your question also.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help.

Comment: You are welcome!